# Google Maps API and increasing accuracy in MS-Edge

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, microsoft-edge

This is my code minus my API key to get a user's current location and it works accurately in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my api key]=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMyLocation(){
 /* Chrome need SSL! */
 var is_chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );
 var is_ssl    = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
 if( is_chrome && ! is_ssl ){
  return false;
 }
 /* HTML5 Geolocation */
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function( position ){ // success cb
   /* Current Coordinate */
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lng = position.coords.longitude;
   var google_map_pos = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
   /* Use Geocoder to get address */
   var google_maps_geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   google_maps_geocoder.geocode(
    { 'latLng': google_map_pos },
    function( results, status ) {
     if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0] ) {
      document.getElementById("myplace").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
      var str = results[0].formatted_address;
      var res = str.split(", ");
      /*Street*/
      document.getElementById('input_14_10').value = res[0];
      /*City*/
      document.getElementById('input_14_12').value = res[1];
      /*State*/
      document.getElementById('input_14_13').value = res[2].substr(0,2);
      /*Zip*/
      document.getElementById('input_14_15').value = res[2].substr(3);
     }
    }
   );
  },
  function(){ // fail cb
  }
 );
};
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id='calcmiles'  onclick='getMyLocation()' value='Push to Get My Location' ><br> 
<font style="font-size: 200% !important"><b><a id='myplace'></a></b></font>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"></input>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="route" disabled="true"></input>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input>
<table id="address">
     <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="input_14_10" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="input_14_12" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="input_14_13" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="input_14_15" disabled="true"></input></td>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Phone Number</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="phone"></input></td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox it consistently correctly represents the user's current location but in Edge It is off by several addresses.  What can be done to increase the accuracy in Edge?

Comment: Make sure that you are logged on to your google account when using your web app from Edge...Perhaps the google map api, gives a lower accuracy if the geo position query comes from a anonymous google user. Test by using the InPrivate and Incognito versions of your browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you are getting different lat/lon from `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` or if you are getting different results from the geocoded?

If you are getting different Lat/Lon, one possible fix is to pass the optional `PositionOptions` object to `getCurrentPosition()`. The `PositionsOptions` takes a flag for `enableHighAccuracy` that might get better results from Edge.

You pass it as the final parameter like this:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function( position ){ // success cb);
    // ...your function 
    },
    function(){ } // fail cb,
    options
)
```

Not sure if this is the issue, but worth a try.